# Sed Regular expression to extract MAC address from file

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to know what are changes I need to make to my regular expression to work with 'sed' in Linux (actually, I am working with (GNU sed v4.8) in OpenWRT).
I have a file containing a list of DHCP leases (dhcp.leases):

```
1660667709 6a:51:a1:e1:10:48 192.168.0.10 client-1 01:6a:51:a1:e1:10:48
1660667634 6b:52:a2:e2:11:cd 10.33.10.115 user3 01:6b:52:a2:e2:11:cd
1660667533 6c:53:a3:e3:12:0f 192.60.200.20 grumpy-user 01:6c:53:a3:e3:12:0f
1660667538 6d:54:a4:e4:13:ef 192.60.200.34 not-friendly 01:6d:54:a4:e4:13:ef
1660667541 6f:55:a5:e5:14:44 10.73.10.160 some-user *
1660667543 60:56:a6:e6:15:b6 10.22.50.10 another 01:60:56:a6:e6:15:b6
1660667548 61:57:a7:e7:16:16 10.200.4.145 * 01:61:57:a7:e7:16:16
1660667548 62:58:a8:e8:17:65 192.60.200.30 no-user 01:62:58:a8:e8:17:65
```

I would like a regular expression to print only the first MAC address of a specific client. For example '6c:53:a3:e3:12:0f' for 'grumpy-user'.

Using [RegExr website](https://regexr.com/) I created a regular expression that works fine over there. It shows all the groups and I could extract the one I need (group 1). The expression works even if the MAC addresses are expressed in a different format (using '-' as separator, or dots, or if the hex characters are lower or upper-case):

```
(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-\\.]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))(.+)(grumpy-user)
```

When using the website I see that the capture group 1 is what I really need, but I don't know how I can translate that to sed. The interesting part is that I have used regular expressions created there than seem to work fine.

Anyway, the command that I tried that is not working is:

```
cat dhcp.leases | sed -r 's/(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-\\.]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))(.+)(grumpy-user)/\3/g'
```

I tried reading from multiple answers to try to figure out the expression that will work, but I ended up nowhere. I also tried **grep** with no luck.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? As you can tell, I am no Regular Expression guru!

Comment: Is sed mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer after playing with it for while, and of course it happened right after I posted.
What is working for me is:

```
cat dhcp.leases.test | sed -rn 's/.*(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-\\.]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})).+grumpy-user.*/\1/p'
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it might help someone with a similar problem.

Just in case, the **-r** switch tells sed to use the extended regular expressions, and the **-n** switch tells it not to print the pattern space.

In my expression, I am basically capturing only one group that contains the MAC address (the portion between parentheses). Before that group I can have any character, and the group must be followed by any characters up to the required username and any other remaining character(s) after that. With **\1** I print the only group captured.